# Gnuplot: Creating Datasets using the Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, dataset, gnuplot

I need to color my data in two colors. So I'm using the 'index' property to define the linestyle of each dataset.
When the data is read from a file the sets are seperated by two empty lines. That's working fine.
But when I'm trying to enter the data into gnuplot using the keyboard, the double lines are ignored and the data is seen as one dataset. What am I doing wrong?

The data must be entered using the keyboard, I can't use the detour way using files...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you post a sample of your code where it works when you use a data file? This would make it easier to look into your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether I understand your intention completely but it looks as if this could be of help:

It’s even possible to read data from standard input multiple times within the same
plot command:

`plot '-', '-'`

will read data until an end-of-file character is encountered and then expect to read more data (for the second “file”) until finding a second EOF character. Of course, the data entered at a prompt this way can have multiple columns, from which we can select some with using, and all the other features of the plot command can be used as well.